# RNG for my text-based game in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming and to test myself, I tried making a text-based game. The problem is, in the selection of dialogue, I included a speech check where it will be based on RNG but I just can't get it right. I am sorry if this is a dumb question but I am really lost.

Here is the part of the code:

```
def scene1part2():
    option2 = ["1. Okay. Here you go you cheeky guard.", "2. What?! No.", "3. [Luck] Let me in for free?"]
    option2_1 = ["Okay. Here you go you cheeky guard.", "What?! No.", "3.Let me in for free?"]
    for o2 in option2:
    print(o2)
    answer2 = input("> ")
    if answer2 == "1":
        print(option2_1[0])
        print("Lost 500 Chromosomes")
        print("Guard: You can go ahead now.")
        chromosomes = (chromosomes) - 500
    elif answer2 == "2":
        print(option2_1[1])
        print("Guard: Get out of here then you piece of crap.")
        sys.exit()
    elif answer2 == "3":
        for rng in range(1):
            rng = random.randint(1, 101)
            print(rng)
            if rng <= 50:
                print("Guard: You wish. Get out of here then you piece of crap. ")
            elif rng >= 50:
                print("Guard: *sigh* Okay. Come inside already")
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong? It's hard to help when we don't know "what do you expect" vs "what comes out"

Comment: When I type my option which is the one with the RNG, it doesn't show anything and it just gives me an exit code. But it's okay, I've figured it out. Sorry for giving a bland question. I'm relatively new to the site and to programming :)

Comment: @remissingo It's ok. You're welcomed here!

Comment: Other quick notes: you can subtract from a variable by doing `chromosomes -= 500`. Also, rather than `sys.exit()` you probably just want to use `return` but I'm going to guess that was just in there for testing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have used the same variable twice.

Your loop:

for rng in range(1):

uses the same variable as the randomizer variable.

rng = random.randint(1, 101)

Switch a variable name and it should work fine!

Also, use a shorter range to minimize errors, 1-2 rather than 1-101

Hope this helps!